# How to construct a string using the keys of an array?

Tags: php, arrays

I need help in constructing a string concatenated using **comma** based on the key values of an array. It could be achieved using `foreach` loop, but is there any method similar to using `implode()` ?

This is the sample array I use,

```
array(5) { 
    [2280]=> string(1) "1" 
    [2138]=> string(1) "1" 
    [3194]=> string(1) "1" 
    [2396]=> string(1) "1" 
    [2944]=> string(1) "1" 
}
```

Thanks in advance !!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

say your array is named `$array`, you can do it like that:

```
implode(',',array_keys($array))
```

[array_keys](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php) will return the keys of your array in another array, which will then be used to implode the keys into the string you want.

that would generate the following string:

```
"2280,2138,3194,2396,2944"
```

Answer (score 1):

Can be done like:

```
echo implode(', ', array_keys(array(2280 => '1', 2138 => '1')));
```

Output:

```
2280, 2138
```